# Java - ImageIcon won't show image

Tags: java

```
searchIcon = new ImageIcon( "searchIcon.png" );

searchIconLabel = new JLabel();
searchIconLabel.setIcon(searchIcon);

....

searchHorizontalPanel.add( searchIconLabel );
```

I'm trying to load the icon but it won't show up. The jpanel is within a boxlayout. I don't know if that messes things up. It's strange because I can add pretty much anything else except icon images. I went through the debugger and searchIcon is showing the width and height to be -1. Does this mean the image is not being loaded?

Comment: The majority of your questions are covered in the Swing tutorial. Why can't you actually read the tutorial first before posting a question? I just gave you a link to the tutorial, yet you have yet to read it and continue to ask follow up questions becuase you didn't understand the original one line solution.

Comment: camickr, I always look through javadocs and swing tutorials before I come to stack overflow. I've seen that swing tut before and it was not a help to me, mainly because it's first method was not working for me and second I did not want to use getResource method. So, please stop ASSuming. Thanks. Have a nice day.

Comment: I suggest you read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your image file needs to be in the same directory as you are running the application from.

If its actually in the same directory as the class making the call then you can use:

```
searchIcon = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource("searchIcon.png") );
```

If it is in some arbitrary location then you will need to specify the full path.

Comment: Thanks. I added the full path and it works. It's strange though...in a previous Java program I wrote, I just had the file within the project folder (using NetBeans) and it loaded fine.

Comment: This poses a problem however. What if it is not run on the same computer? The path will be different. How do you add a path that will work on all computers?

Comment: -1 If its actually, in the same directory as the class making the call then the code posted with the question will work. Thats why the better answer is to actually read the tutorial so you understand whats going on and don't take the shortcut answer just because somebody posts a line of code, because you still don't understand why it works. Do some basic reading on your own.

Comment: thats incorrect, the code posted looks in the directory it is *run from*, not the same directory as the class

Comment: @Plissken, better to package your images as resources with your classes. That avoids the problem of having to specify the full path.

Answer (score 1):

> I went through the debugger and
>   searchIcon is showing the width and
>   height to be -1. Does this mean the
>   image is not being loaded?

Yes.

Read the JLabel API and you will find a link to the Swing tutorial on "How to Use Lables" which has a working example.

You will also find a section on "How to Use Icons" which shows all the different ways to specify the icon location correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't imported java.awt.BufferedImage then the computer would not be able to allow access to Java to load the images.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29980680)