# How do I display images from an array?

Tags: java, swing

How can I fix it so that the images appear?
I'm using NetBeans 11.2 Java Gradle
I am trying to make images of a car go forward.
The `JPanel` pops up but no images are shown! I've been at it for a long time trying to figure this out.
No error message shows up.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private final Timer animate;
    private final ImageIcon ImageArray[];
    private int delay = 50, FrameCount = 200, Currentframe = 0;

    public Main() {
        ImageArray = new ImageIcon[FrameCount];
        for (int i = 1; i < ImageArray.length; i++) {
            ImageArray[i] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Cartest (" + i + ").jpg"));
        }
        animate = new Timer(delay, this);
        animate.start();
    }

    public void paintConponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (Currentframe >= ImageArray.length) {
            Currentframe = 0;
        }
        Currentframe++;
        ImageArray[Currentframe].paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        JFrame f= new JFrame("hello");
        Main s = new Main();
        f.add(s);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(400,400);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you registered the ActionListener? I don't see it anywhere

Comment: Have you tried with `classpath:` prefix or full path to the image like it's recommended here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422160/java-imageicon-wont-show-image

Comment: @tibetiroka How to i register ActionListener??

Comment: @tibetiroka I looked over the question and solution for said form and if your implying if the file was within my netbeans application it is. I dont know what classpath: is

Comment: @AbeZINX I assume you want to show the next image after x seconds. You can use a timer for that. Try using a javax timer with 'this' as the action listener.

Comment: @tibetiroka did you miss this line in the code: `animate = new Timer(delay, this);` I believe this is what you refer to as _registered the ActionListener_

Comment: My bad. Thank you.

Comment: Is the code in your question your actual code? You wrote the name of the method wrong. You wrote `paintCo` ___n___ `ponent` instead of `paintCo` ___m___ `ponent`.

Comment: Well spotted @Abra! That's a good reason to always add the `@Override` notation. OP: We can't run the code without images.. One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. The code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556).

Comment: @Abra Thank you so much I'm an idiot this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others pointed out, you made a typo in the `paintComponent` method's name. The second problem is you'll get a `NullpointerException` due to line `currentFrame = 0;` (after the first iteration) as you started filling the imageArray from index 1.
There's nothing wrong with the `getResource` part of your code, as it would've have thrown an exception on that line if no image was to be found.

**Advice**:
Use the `Override` annotation when overriding a superclass' method. The compiler will start complaining about the annotation's incorrect use in case you made a typo.

This answer isn't *necessarily* indicative of how to do things. But it does make your code work:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private final Timer animate;
    private final ImageIcon imageArray[];
    private int delay = 50, frameCount = 200, currentFrame = 0;

    public Main() {

        imageArray = new ImageIcon[frameCount];


        for (int i = 1; i < imageArray.length; i++) {

            imageArray[i] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Cartest (" + i + ").jpg"));

        }

        animate = new Timer(delay, this);
        animate.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        currentFrame++;
        if (currentFrame == imageArray.length) {
            currentFrame = 1;
        }

        imageArray[currentFrame].paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        JFrame f= new JFrame("hello");
        Main s = new Main();
        f.add(s);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(400,400);
    }

}
```

Comment: (1-) Don't use getGraphics() to do painting. The proper way is to override the `paintComponent(...)` method as the OP does in the original code. In your Timer code you then invoke repaint() on the panel the Swing will invoke the paintComponent(...) method.

Comment: @camickr. Changed it so it's no longer a display of bad practice.

Comment: @TimonNetherlands Thanks it was the spelling mistake have a great day

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of animating a car image.  The OP didn't provide car images, so I created one.

[image: Car Image]

Here's the GUI I created.  The car moves from right to left.

[image: Car Animation GUI]

I use the [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern when I create a Swing application.  This model enforces a separation of concerns and allows me to focus on one part of the Swing application at a time.

So, the first thing I did was to create a `Car` class.  The `Car` class holds the position of the image and the image itself.

Generally, in a Swing application, you read all the resources first, then you create your GUI.  If reading the resources takes a long time, you can read the resources in a separate Thread that will run while you build the GUI.

Since I had one resource, I read it.

After I created the `Car` class, I created a view with one `JFrame` and one drawing `JPanel`.  Generally, you create one drawing `JPanel` and draw everything on that one drawing `JPanel`.

The controller in this application is the Swing `Timer`.  The `Timer` moves the car from right to left and starts over when the car reaches the left edge of the drawing `JPanel`.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class CarAnimationGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CarAnimationGUI());
    }
    
    private int drawingAreaWidth;
    private int drawingAreaHeight;
    private int startX, startY;
    
    private Car car;
    
    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    
    public CarAnimationGUI() {
        this.drawingAreaWidth = 600;
        this.drawingAreaHeight = 200;
        this.car = new Car();
        
        BufferedImage image = car.getImage();
        this.startX = drawingAreaWidth - image.getWidth();
        this.startY = drawingAreaHeight - image.getHeight();
        car.setLocation(new Point(startX, startY));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Car Animation GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(drawingAreaWidth, 
                drawingAreaHeight);
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        Timer animate = new Timer(50, new CarMover(startX, startY));
        animate.start();
    }
    
    public void repaint() {
        drawingPanel.repaint();
    }
    
    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        public DrawingPanel(int width, int height) {
            this.setBackground(new Color(154, 232, 208));
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
            BufferedImage image = car.getImage();
            Point point = car.getLocation();
            
            g.drawImage(image, point.x, point.y, this);
        }
        
    }
    
    private class CarMover implements ActionListener {

        private final int startX, startY;
        private int x;
        
        public CarMover(int startX, int startY) {
            this.startX = startX;
            this.startY = startY;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            x -= 3;
            x = (x < 0) ? startX : x;
            car.setLocation(new Point(x, startY));
            repaint();
        }
        
    }
    
    public class Car {
        
        private final BufferedImage image;
        
        private Point location;

        public Car() {
            this.image = setImage();
        }
        
        private BufferedImage setImage() {
            try {
                return ImageIO.read(getClass()
                        .getResourceAsStream("/car.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        public BufferedImage getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public void setLocation(Point location) {
            this.location = location;
        }

        public Point getLocation() {
            return location;
        }
        
    }

}
```